# When I am importing `http.server` from the idle it works, but when I run a python file having `import http.server` there is an error

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, module

When I Am Using:

```
>>> import http.server
```

in the `IDLE` there isn't any error.

 But When I am Using This Piece Of Code:

```
import http.server
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from http.server import HTTPServer

def run(server_class = HTTPServer, handler_class = BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd=server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()


run()
```

There Is An Error Which Is As Follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2195, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toton/Projects/http.py", line 1, in <module>
    import http.server
  File "/home/toton/Projects/http.py", line 1, in <module>
    import http.server
ImportError: No module named 'http.server'; 'http' is not a package
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have named your file as `http.py`, Thus it is overriding the original module `http`

To solve

- change the name of the file to something else
- Remove the `pyc` file
- Run the program again